# Wordpress - How do I make this?

Tags: wordpress, post, comments

I would like to make a "Comment" section on every of my page on my wordpress website.

So if you head to http://www.lolcounter.com/champions/lee-sin, You can see on top of the page the "General Counter Tips" with bellow it, 4 comments.

There is more comment then this and you can see it if you click the "View More Counter Tips" and you can post a tip if you click "Submit a Counter Tip".

My question is, how do I make something similar to this with wordpress ? I actually have multiple page that I want to add this feature on them, but all of them need to have different comments.

Do I make this with a custom post type ? Or I add everything into a table into my DB? or is there any other way?

Thanks for any help :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom content plugins for that. Just use a comment one that you can place anywhere in your page. Or structure it so your content fits better with the standard comment system.

Plugins help standardize your site so you only have to update the code in only one place to update it across the site.

WordPress generally uses something like [spacer] as a way of dropping plugins into certain pages.

https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/wordpress_plugins.htm

Here is a plugin that works as a solution to your problem.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Look near the bottom.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/screenshots/

Search for a call to comment_form() function if you want to do it manually.

Remember that WordPress is all done in PHP. So if you know how PHP is done you can go make the calls you want yourself by editing the templates under

appearance > editor.

Comment: I see, well I am looking for something more "permanant" I would say. Something that I would code, I am not too sure to add a plugin to do this job. Thanks for you answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the Link, Ive used ACF a bit a while ago but I don't understand how I would make this work as a comment section, can you brievly tell me how you would see this ? Thanks !

Comment: BTW, I am a programmer myself, but I would like to know the most effective way to code this since I am not 100% familiar with wordpress :)

Comment: I know about comment_form :)
The this is that I want multiple comment form in the same page, for other feature. That's why I was wondering how I could make this things work out. (I know PHP and page-template :P I still have some good knowledge about WP)

Comment: So is that enough for you to be able to figure it out? You just need different instances of the comment form in the same page or custom template.

Comment: Yes I think I will try to make this thing work with multiple instance of the wordpress comment_form. Ill do some research on how I could do this. Thank you guys !